# Help identifying IC damaged by wrong voltage

Tags: identification, damage, hard-drive

I accidentally fried an IC when switching out a power supply; sent 12V instead of 5V. I've been trying to find some information on this drive, a Corsair M500 240GB, (CT240M500SSD1) - maybe a datasheet, but I haven't found zilch.

IC below - the damage is pretty visible. Maybe it's some sort of regulator? Not sure:

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure it's a regulator but also pretty sure it's not the only part which is fried. Once the regulator burned out, all the parts behind it are toast, too. If you had valueable data on this disk, you had a backup.

Comment: You best bet may be to look for a used drive of the exact same type on eBay, Kijiji, Craig's list or whatever. We are not going to get anything from that photo. Sometimes, with older drives like this one, you can just swap boards and it will fire up and you can get your data off. Or pay someone to do it for you (I would expect to pay at least $1K-$2K locally).

Comment: Out of curiosity, did this happen from modular power supply cables from different manufacturers? Some of them will plug in perfectly to their competitors but have the 12/5 swapped compared to others. Horrible.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yep, the cables were identical and I thought I had replaced them all. I should have done another check. I fried about six drives, but most of them contained nothing of value. This one has a few stuff, but again nothing critical. Just figured I'd try.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany This drive is an SSD. "Swapping boards" would amount to swapping the entire drive, not just the controller.

Comment: @duskwuff Oh, sorry to hear that. In that case, I think OP is thoroughly scuppered.